# Is there a built-in way in Angular to apply a full filter expression?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

#### A question in a nutshell:

How can I get a filter expression `"| filter1:arg1:arg2 | filter2:arg1"` that would be typically specified in an Angular expression, like so: `{{ model | filter1:arg1:arg2 | filter2:arg1 }}` and apply it programmatically?

I could use regex, and then `$filter(name)(arg1, arg2)`, but I was wondering if there was a built-in way.

#### Broader context

I need a way to filter what an `<input type="text">` tag shows when it's not focused without affecting the underlying model. This would be similar to a cell in excel which may have a value of 12.3556, but could render 12.36 if you specify a number with 2 decimal points. However, when it's being edited, it would show the underlying full value.

So, I built a directive `viewFilter` that `requires` `ngModel`, such that I could do the following:

`<input ng-model="data" view-filter="filter1:arg1:arg2 | filter2:arg1" type="text">`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one of the following, assuming this code is inside a directive:

```
scope.$eval( "data |" + attrs.viewFilter );
```

Another possibility is:

```
$parse( "data | " + attrs.viewFilter )( scope );
```

The `$parse` service has the advantage that [you can specify locals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) for the expression being parsed.